# Is it neccesery to store Access Tokens?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-fql

I'm new to FB application Development. 
Just clear me, after user installing my application imma getting their access token is it necessary to store those access tokens to access their data and post behalf of them or is there any way to get all users access tokens who are all using my app....

Comment: Are you talking about making posts on behalf of a user from a cron jobs etc.? If so you would most likely want to get an extended access token. Access tokens do expire however, so there is no guarantee that any access token you have stored would necessarily be valid when you came to use it

Comment: If you want to post on behalf of the user when he is offline, yes you have to. Just don't forget to get the long lived token for 60 day access (short lived only last 30 mins)